# C# - If/Else Help [User and Computer Input Interaction]

Tags: c#

I am trying to figure out a way to get the Computer player to respond to my moves basically by seeing "This spot is taken, I should see if another is free and take it".

So far, I'm not making any improvements (been like 5 hours). I want the computer to realize if a certain button (which it chose at random) is taken, it should consider another choice. Not sure where the if/else should actually go or where/what I should put in for it to try another location.

Here's the snippet of code with comments on my idea (likely wrong placement where I want to do things):

```
if (c.Enabled == true) //if the button is free
{
    if ((c.Name == "btn" + Convert.ToString(RandomGenerator.GenRand(1, 9)) )) //if a specific button is free
    {
        if ((c.Text != "X")) //if its empty
        {
            //do this
            c.Text = "O"; //O will be inside the button
            c.Enabled = false; //button can no long be used
            CheckComputerWinner(); //check if it finishes task
            return;
        }
        else //if it is an X
        {
            //try a different button choice instead
            //see if that button is empty
                //do stuff
            //else
                //... repeat until all buttons are checked if free
        }
    }
}
```

My question is simply: How can I fix this and understand what is going on? Or do it more efficiently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create an array with those buttons so you don't have to check names:

```
Button[9] gameField;
```

Creating a `[3,3]` array might be more intuitive, but for this case a plain array is easier to work with.
Then, you could count how many of them are free:

```
int freeCount = gameField.Count(b => b.Text != "X");
```

If you want to randomly select one of the free ones, generate a random number in the range `0 - (freeCount - 1)` and select the appropriate button:

```
int offset = RandomGenerator.GenRand(0, freeCount - 1);
Button target = gameField.Where(b => b.Text != "X").Skip(offset).FirstOrDefault();
if (target != null) {
    // check it
}
```

The extension method `Where` filters your buttons to only return the free ones. `Skip` will skip the specified number of elements (for random selection) and `FirstOrDefault` returns the first element of the resulting sequence (or `null` if there is none).

Note: You might want to check for some cases before randomly selecting a field to make your AI a bit more ambitious:

- Has the computer player two O in a row with the third field being free? If so, select that one.
- Has the human player two X in a row with the third field being free? If so, select that one.

There are tricks to exploit that strategy and there are also better heuristics, but i'll leave that to you.

Comment: Can I keep everything on the player side the same and just implement the array for the Computer player?

Comment: Yes, because the array will hold references to the buttons (after you assigned them of course). So if the player puts an X on a button, that will also be visible when using the array.

Comment: Each of my buttons are assigned as "btn1, btn2, btn3, etc". Does that mean I need to change those?

Comment: No, you don't need to, you can keep the old variables. You can just initialize the array like this: `gamefield = new Button[] { btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4, ... }`

Comment: Alright, makes sense. :)
I see you put gamefield, was this assumed? I have a Form with a menu strip and these 9 buttons (and the code behind to check winners and stuff). Would gamefield have to be instantiated somewhere?

Comment: Yes, you'll need to declare it as a private field in the code-behind. You can initialize it in the constructor, *after* `IntializeComponent()`

Comment: Got it. Put everything in, but after 1 time around (I go, then computer goes)...the computer never goes again. Why is this?

Comment: Plus, it always goes to btn9...if i take that spot--it places an O as well.

Comment: I got it to do more moves, but its predictable placement. No matter where I go first (other than button 6) it will go to button 6.

Comment: @DwellingPlace Maybe your RandomGenerator is always returning the same value? This could happen if you recreate it every time with the same seed.

Comment: got it. I was still using `c` instead of `target` and forgot to remove something within   `RandomGenerator.GenRand(0, freeCount - 1);` . Asked another question and got help catching it. 

Thanks every much for the explanations and help :D Solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your looking for a while loop here. You can modify your code as follows:

```
Button c;
// here you look for a Button within the Controls of your Form. It stops when an Enabled Button with Text != "X" is found
do
{
    c = this.Controls.Find("btn" + Convert.ToString(RandomGenerator.GenRand(1, 9)), true).FirstOrDefault() as Button;
} while (c == null || !c.Enabled || c.Text == "X");
c.Text = "O"; //O will be inside the button
c.Enabled = false; //button can no long be used
CheckComputerWinner(); //check if it finishes task
return;
```

Comment: You're right, it's for web controls. It's Find, not FindControl (look at the edit)