# C# - Why is the execution of these different codes giving me the same result?

Tags: c#

My first code executes and after I make my move, the computer always tries to get the bottom right-hand spot of a Tic Tac Toe board:

```
private void ComputersTurn()
    {
        Control.ControlCollection coll = this.Controls;
        foreach (Control c in coll)//for each button in form
        {
            if ((c != null) && (c is Button))//if c is a button and c has a value
            {
                if ((c.Name != "btnNewGame") && (c.Name != "btnExit")) // if the button isnt btn new game or exit
                {

                    if (c.Enabled == true) //if a button has an X
                    {
                        c.Text = "O"; //place an O
                        c.Enabled = false; //in a empty button
                        CheckComputerWinner(); //check if it wins
                        return; //return result
                    }//end of if
               }//end of if 2
            }//end of if 1
        }//end of foreach
    }//end of ComputersTurn
```

The second code, which I got help with...does the same exact thing:

```
private void ComputersTurn()
    {
        Control.ControlCollection coll = this.Controls;
        foreach (Control c in coll)//for each button in form
        {
            if ((c != null) && (c is Button))//if c is a button and c has a value
            {
                if ((c.Name != "btnNewGame") && (c.Name != "btnExit")) // if the button isnt btn new game or exit
                {
                    gamefield = new Button[] { btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4, btn5, btn6, btn7, btn8, btn9 };
                    int freeCount = gamefield.Count(b => b.Text != "X");

                    int offset = RandomGenerator.GenRand(0 - 8, freeCount - 1);
                    Button target = gamefield.Where(b => b.Text != "X").Skip(offset).FirstOrDefault(); ;
                    if (target != null)//if target has an X
                    {
                        // check it
                        if (c.Enabled == true)
                        {
                            c.Text = "O"; //O will be inside the button
                            c.Enabled = false; //button can no long be used
                            CheckComputerWinner(); //check if it finishes task
                            return;
                        }
                    }
               }
            }
        }
    }//end of ComputersTurn
```

Random Generator

```
public static class RandomGenerator
    {
        private static readonly Random _random = new Random();

        public static int GenRand(int x, int y)
        {
            return _random.Next(x, y);
        }
    }
```

I don't understand why. The second one is aimed for the computer to be random, first one is set up to be predictable. Why are they both doing the same thing?

Comment: How is `c` defined? And what do you mean by "the same result"?

Comment: Because somehow the code is broken? 'unpredictable' means it may work :-)

Comment: Hard to acually say why it doesnt provide a random result when the code that generates the random value is not available :(

Comment: what does `.FirstOrDefault();` do? could it set target to 0 ?

Comment: Same result as in they both cause the computer to act the same exact way. Same moves every time...where in the second snippet, I expected the computer to make random choices.

Comment: @itsid `FirstOrDefault` is a standard method for all classes implementing IEnumerable http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx

Comment: @itsid http://stackoverflow.com/a/14997780/2094247 
Thats where I learned the second piece

Comment: Why is your lower bound in the random 0-8. Wouldnt you want to start at 0 and then random up to how many available positions you have? RandomGenerator.GenRand(0, freeCount).  And since the second param is exclusive you wouldnt need -1. He will only give random values 0-8 if you pass the 0, 9 params

Comment: @Evelie AH! That solved the random issue! Now the Computer is free! Nice! Thanks Evelie, worked like a charm with RobEpstein 's answer <3!

Comment: Awsome! Glad I could help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second solution never uses the `target` value. It uses the current looped value `c`. Change all the check it logic to use `target` instead of `c`. You can also eliminate the outer loop and two outer if statements all together.

Comment: That changed it a bit. Instead now it always picks the top left hand side. However, like the old first code, it does change its position based on if it wins or loses (which I didn't code).

Comment: Glad that helped. Best of luck with your project!

Comment: Ah, got it @Evelie tackled the other issue. Thanks <3!

Comment: It seems as though your original question has been answered. SO is not a place to have your project written for you. Best of luck!

Comment: Yep, I love this place because of that (hence why I left out certain things). Better to understand what I'm putting in and now I know a bit more.